# read_tsv Parsing data incorrectly into R

Tags: r, readr

I'm currently working on a Mac OS and am trying to use `read_tsv` from the `tidyverse` to read in the below `txt` file:

```
igg oxygen
881 34.6
1290    45
2147    62.3
1909    58.9
1282    42.5
1530    44.3
2067    67.9
1982    58.5
1019    35.6
1651    49.6
752 33
1687    52
1782    61.4
1529    50.2
969 34.1
1660    52.5
2121    69.9
1382    38.8
1714    50.6
1959    69.4
1158    37.4
965 35.1
1456    43
1273    44.1
1418    49.8
1743    54.4
1997    68.5
2177    69.5
1965    63
1264    43.2
```

However, when I try to read the file in, I get the following issues:

```
exerimmun <- read_tsv(file = "./exerimmun.txt")

── Column specification ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  i = col_logical(),
  col_logical()
)

Warning: 124 parsing failures.
row col           expected    actual                                        file
  1  i  1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE                                     './exerimmun.txt'
  1  -- 2 columns          1 columns                           './exerimmun.txt'
  2  i  1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE                                     './exerimmun.txt'
  2     1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE                                     './exerimmun.txt'
  3  i  1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE                                     './exerimmun.txt'
... ... .................. ......... ...........................................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

As far as I can tell, the data seems to be correctly parsed in the `txt` file, so I'm not sure why I'm getting issues reading it into `R`. Here is the result when I use `problems(exerimmun)`

```
> problems(exerimmun)
# A tibble: 124 x 5
     row col   expected           actual      file                                       
   <int> <chr> <chr>              <chr>       <chr>                                      
 1     1 "i"   1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 2     1  NA   2 columns          "1 columns" './exerimmun.txt'
 3     2 "i"   1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 4     2 ""    1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 5     3 "i"   1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 6     3  NA   2 columns          "1 columns" './exerimmun.txt'
 7     4 "i"   1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 8     4 ""    1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
 9     5 "i"   1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ""          './exerimmun.txt'
10     5  NA   2 columns          "1 columns" './exerimmun.txt'
# … with 114 more rows
```

To me, this should work fine since the data only has two columns. I'm not sure what I'm missing after looking at documentation for how to read in `txt` files.

Edit: I've tried `read.table("./exerimmun.txt")` and get the following:

```
Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>i'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = "./exerimmun.txt") :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = "./exerimmun.txt") :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = "./exerimmun.txt") :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = "./exerimmun.txt") :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = "./exerimmun.txt") :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `read.table("./exerimmun.txt")`.

Comment: It looks like there's an unexpected (and unprinted) character at the beginning of your file, that hasn't been copied across to your example.

Comment: @Miff I downloaded the data from https://online.stat.psu.edu/onlinecourses/sites/stat501/files/data/exerimmun.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe easiest to just avoid that function for now?  You can always convert to a `tibble` afterwards.

Here I saved your data as `/tmp/data.tsv`, and I am using plain base R to deal with it:

```
> x <- read.table("/tmp/data.tsv", header=TRUE)
> str(x)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ igg   : int  881 1290 2147 1909 1282 1530 2067 1982 1019 1651 ...
 $ oxygen: num  34.6 45 62.3 58.9 42.5 44.3 67.9 58.5 35.6 49.6 ...
> summary(x)
      igg           oxygen    
 Min.   : 752   Min.   :33.0  
 1st Qu.:1275   1st Qu.:42.6  
 Median :1590   Median :50.0  
 Mean   :1558   Mean   :50.6  
 3rd Qu.:1946   3rd Qu.:60.8  
 Max.   :2177   Max.   :69.9  
>
```

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions on how to easily convert to `tsv`? I used a source online but wasn't sure if there was an easier method on my computer. I tried to just change the file type but that didn't work initially.

Comment: What do you mean by _convert to `tsv`_ ?  To save as? You can see `help(write.table)` for that.